# the meaning of tcpdump output for request/reply to DNS

Tags: linux, tcpdump

following is part of the output of tcpdump:

```
18:34:15.429373 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56078, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 92)
172.31.8.42.47412 > 172.31.0.2.53: 3383+ [1au] A? www.yahoo.com. (64)
18:34:15.431788 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 36898, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 129)
172.31.0.2.53 > 172.31.8.42.47412: 3383 3/0/1 www.yahoo.com. CNAME fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com., fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com. A 98.139.180.149, fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com. A 98.139.183.24 (101)
```

what is the meaning of `3383+`, `3/0/1` and `[1au]`?

I have checked a lot documents for `tcpdump`, but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respectively (i.e. in order):

> id is the answer on a query with number [e.g.] 17991
>
> - a/ the number of answer records
> - /n the number of name server records
> - au the number of additional records

http://nil.uniza.sk/linux-howto/using-tcpdump-diagnostic-dns-debian

(Google result #2 for "tcpdump dns", also for "tcpdump dns format" which was an autocomplete suggestion).

> OUTPUT FORMAT
>
> UDP Name Server Requests
>
> A few anomalies are checked and may result in extra fields enclosed  in
> square  brackets:   If a query contains an answer, authority records or
> additional records section, ancount, nscount, or arcount are printed as
> `[na]', `[nn]' or  `[nau]' where n is the appropriate count.

```
man tcpdump  # a primary source document for tcpdump
```

---

"id" is nowadays one of the [randomized fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5452#section-9.2), although in the older examples you will see sequential IDs.  This field could be used to distinguish different requests between the same parties, even when packets are re-ordered.

The response record counts look consistent to me.

I am not sure why your request is showing the "anomaly".